# UIImageView _isResizable: Unrecognized Selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, compiler-errors

I have the following code to display an image on a brand but I get an UIImageView error.
I resize my image of size 800x600 to fit to the size of the screen of the iPhone.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.portallzc.com/galerias/galeria_Portal%20de%20Lazaro%20Cardenas/Club%2033/800/p16jklq9uj1f7a1c6tckkjrg1i8015.JPG"];
NSData * urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: urlData];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0.0f, 40.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[setImage image: image];
```

> Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [UIImageView _isResizable]:
>   unrecognized selector instance stmt to 0x6b8bb70'

Comment: what is  [setImage image: image]; ? is your object called setImage ? Pretty bad name

Comment: Sorry is:
image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[image setImage image: image];

Comment: Why are you setting an imageView's image equal to the imageView itself?

Comment: Still, that signature is not valid syntax.

Comment: I have: 
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.portallzc.com/galerias/galeria_Portal%20de%20Lazaro%20Cardenas/Club%2033/800/p16jklq9uj1f7a1c6tckkjrg1i8015.JPG"];
    NSData * urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData: urlData];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake (0.0f, 40.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    
    imagen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
    [imagen setImage: imagen];

Comment: Now it is, in your second comment you had another syntax. But now i see what you are doing wrong.  imagen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect]; [imagen setImage: imagen]; That doesnt make sense. you supply a UIImageView where you want to supply a UIImage

Comment: still imagen is a uiimageview i guess , xcode has intellisense , please use it wisely.

Comment: Ever looked at compiler warnings and errors?

Answer (score 3):

The Error occur because you attempt to treat UIImageView as an UIImage.

```
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[myImageView setImage: image];
```

If the error disappear try to check

```
[self.view addsubview:myImageView];
```

to make your imageview link to display screen.

If it still not appear try to check layer of your image view.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the naming of your variables.
What you do is :

```
 [imagen setImage: imagen]
```

what you want to do is :

```
 [imagen setImage: image];
```

I extracted that from our conversation in the comments of your question.
This is not reflected in your question. Maybe your question cod is out of sync with what you wrote in your program. have a look at your own comments to understand what i mean.

Comment: I already have it as your you've said but doesn't show me the image for that? Measures will be?
imagen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
[imagen setImage:image];

Comment: @MovileMX, Have you tried logging image to see if it's not nil?